# MYSQL: LOAD DATA IN FILE ??

Tags: md5, sql, mysql

Всем привет, не как не могу разобраться с LOAD DATA IN FILE, вот пример моей проблемы

Есть файл 1.txt его структура:

```
....
Молоко
Кефир
Бидончик
Йогурт
Вода
Водка
Воды
....
```

Допустим там слов тысяч 300.

Мне нужно загрузить эти слова в базу данных допустим : base

Вот структура базы и таблицы.

```
/* Создание основной базы данных. */

CREATE DATABASE `base`;

/* Работа с базой данных base. */

USE `base`;

/* Создание таблицы list. */

CREATE TABLE `list` (
  `slovo` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `md5slovo` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`slovo`)
);
```

Мне нужно добавить слова из файла 1.txt в эту таблицу через load data in file но в файле один столбец строк а в таблице 2, мне нужно сначала добавить содержание файла, то есть все слова с поле slovo а в поле md5slovo добавить MD5 хеш от этого слова, знаю что есть чтото типо select md5(`admin`) но не знаю как использовать...

Answer (score 7):

Первый запрос:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name.txt' INTO TABLE `list` LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (`slovo`)
```

Запрос второй

```
UPDATE `list` SET `md5slovo` = md5(`slovo`)
```

P.S. Если файл загружается с клиентского хоста, то в первом запросе добавляете *LOCAL*

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ...
```